# How to add an entry to the model has_many: through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :sites, through: :accounts
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :projects, through: :accounts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :project
end

p = Project.find(1)

2.1.4 :011 >   p.sites.create({"url"=>"site.ru", "accounts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"mail@site.ru"}}})
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO `sites` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `url`) VALUES ('2015-09-04 07:09:53', '2015-09-04 07:09:53', 'site.ru')
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `accounts` (`created_at`, `email`, `site_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-09-04 07:09:53', 'mail@site.ru', 3, '2015-09-04 07:09:53')
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `accounts` (`created_at`, `project_id`, `site_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-09-04 07:09:53', 1, 3, '2015-09-04 07:09:53')
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Site id: 3, url: "site.ru", created_at: "2015-09-04 07:09:53", updated_at: "2015-09-04 07:09:53">
```

**Question:**

1. Why are added 2 record?
2. To add a single entry in the Account model with fields site_id, project_id, email?

Comment: your question in not clear?

Answer (score 0):

The first account record is created automatically, because the `Site` is related to the `Project` through the `Account`.

The second record is created because you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts` in your `Site` model, and you pass the nested attributes while creating the `Site` record.

Could you clarify, what you want to archieve?

Comment: Like using a hash
{"url"=>"site.ru", "accounts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"mail@site.ru"}}}

Add
INSERT INTO `sites` (`url`) VALUES ('site.ru')
INSERT INTO `accounts` (`project_id`, `site_id`, `email`) VALUES (1, 3, 'mail@site.ru')